# helvetica ttf or alternatives please!

Tags: fonts

Is Helvetica available in ttf format? If not, what might be some good alternatives? I would appreciate any links to download on ttf format, thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming-related question. However, a simple Google search might lead you to http://www.fonts.com/FindFonts/detail.htm?siteID=TDWV&productID=99502&pid=242559&productNo=LV413060?lang=EN

Comment: Not even remotely programming related, and easily solvable via Google. Vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

And, to complete the trifecta of answers, see also the Bitstream Vera Sans family: http://www.gnome.org/fonts/

Answer (score 1):

Of course Arial is without the doubt the bastard half brother of Helvetica - and is clearly distinguishable by all 'specialists'. For a good history check http://www.ms-studio.com/articles.html or check out the fantastic doco 'Helvetica'.

Microsoft Sans Serif, like Arial, is bundled with Windows, but is [more Helvetica-like than Arial](http://www.grputland.com/2013/11/multiplatform-helvetica-like-font-stack.html) - provided that you don't need italics.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Arial from the [msttcorefonts](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=34153&package_id=56408) project. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica):

> Monotype's Arial, designed in 1982,
>   while different from Helvetica in some
>   few details, has identical character
>   widths, and is indistinguishable by
>   most non-specialists.

Comment: Arial is NOT a good alternative to Helvetica.

Comment: Based on what? They look pretty much the same here.

Comment: Arial only looks like Helvetica at 12pt and below. Above that it starts to look rubbish fast - even to people who couldn't tell you why.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, I took a poll of 14 people in our office today. I gave them a piece of paper with the classic "The quick brown fox.." on it two times in 28 point font - once in Helvetica, once in Arial, each clearly labelled - printed via a Xerox Workcenter 5638. I then took that sheet away and gave them a sheet with it once in Helvetica and asked them which of the two fonts had been used. 3 of them said Arial, 4 of them said Helvetica, 7 of them were uncomfortable even guessing because they "pretty much look the same". Not scientific, I know, but something to think about.

Comment: http://ilovetypography.com/2007/10/06/arial-versus-helvetica/

Comment: I would agree with the conclusions in that article - thanks, @RasmusStorjohann

Comment: Arial is popular for a reason. You may even be a type designer, but your users probably aren't.